# How to position a Widget at the bottom of a SingleChildScrollView?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to use `SingleChildScrollView` in order to be able to use [keyboard_actions](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/keyboard_actions) so that i can put a "Done" button on top of the keyboard in iOS (using a numeric keyboard at the moment)

The `SingleChildScrollView` will have a column as a child and then a button to be placed at the bottom. I tried using `LayoutBuilder` to enforce a height to the `SingleChildScrollView`.

```dart
LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints:
                BoxConstraints(minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight),
            child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(),
                  // Spacer() ?
                  FlatButton()
                ])));
  });
```

I tried using the `BoxConstraints` with the `maxHeight` attribute, but ultimately the widget wouldn't scrooll up when the keyboard appeared.

Side note: the Scaffold has both `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` and `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` set to `true` (the default value)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The issue with `SingleChildScrollView` is that it `shrikwrap` it's children.
So to have auto size widget in between - we need to use `MediaQuery` to get the screen height & `SizedBox` to expand - `SingleChildScrollView`.

Here Button will be at bottom of screen.

working Code:

```
double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    SingleChildScrollView(
          child: SizedBox(
              height: height,
              child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Dummy'),
                        Text('Dummy'),
                        Text('Dummy'),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Spacer(),
                    FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text('Demo'),
                    )
                  ])),
        )
```

Comment: Thank you! I used this same solution for other parts of my project, but I don't know why I decided to complicate this one.

Comment: When the keypad opens, it says: "Overflow by 104 pixels." But i guess, SingleChilScrollview should be scrolling. but in this case, scrollview is not scrolling

Comment: if you have an AppBar then your FlatButton will be off screen

Comment: This solution is not the most viable, as the widget inside the sizedBox has a limited size as well as the number of items inside, causing screen overflow.

Comment: You do not need to query for height to do this in React Native, and you should not have to in Flutter. This is a dirty hack which causes another render.

Answer (score 32):

The chosen answer doesn't really work, as using a SizedBox restrict the max size of the Column to the height of the screen, so you can't put as many widgets as you want in it (or they will go off-screen without beeing scrollable).

This solution will work no matter of many widgets are in the column:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18711#issuecomment-505791677

Important note: It will only work if the widgets in the column have a fixed height (for example TextInputField does NOT have a fixed height). If they have variable a height, wrap them with a Container of fixed height.

Comment: How to implement inside Stack?

Comment: Don't know why your answer is not the marked one. It works hella great!. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 19):

I just copied and pasted here the best solution I found, quoted by @Quentin, elaborated by @NikitaZhelonkin in issue 18711 of Flutter on Github. Simply the perfect solution!

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('AppBar'),
        ),
        body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: constraints.maxWidth, minHeight: constraints.maxHeight),
                  child: IntrinsicHeight(
                    child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: [
                          Text('header'),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.green,
                              child: Text('body'),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text('footer'),
                        ]
                    ),
                  )
              )
          );
        })
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The best way is to use CustomScrollView instead of SingleChildScrollView. When using a SizedBox with height, graphical errors will occur when the widget does not fit and a scroll is needed.

```
CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      SliverFillRemaining(
        hasScrollBody: false,
        child: Colum..
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this workaround appraoch also, You can use padding attribute in SingleChildScrollView like this:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: height),
child: yourWidgets(),
```

while height is the distance far away from top.
You can also use this line to get mobile screen height:

```
double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
```

Answer (score 1):

Let the code speak.

```
class SettingsView extends StatelessWidget {
  const SettingsView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverFillRemaining(
          child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const ColoredBox(
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                  child: SizedBox(height: 100, width: 100,),
                ),
                const Spacer(), // Fill all the spacing between red and blue boxes
                const ColoredBox(
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  child: SizedBox(height: 100, width: 100,),
                ),
                TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('I am a button anchored to the bottom')),
                const SizedBox(height: 20,)
              ]
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Screenshots:

[image: Portrait]

[image: Landscape]

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have found for myself.

Center the widgets and push them from top to bottom with padding.

```
return Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
    //resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
    backgroundColor: PrimaryColor,
    body: Center(
    SingleChildScrollView(child:
      _body())));


Widget _body() {
return Padding(
 padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2.7),
 child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(
        'You have pushed the button this many times:',
      ),
      Visibility(
          visible:
              _userProvider.stateReqVMTokenSocial != 
       StateReqVM.Processing,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
           ...
           ...
           ...
            ],
          )),
      Visibility(
          visible:
              _userProvider.stateReqVMTokenSocial == 
         StateReqVM.Processing,
          child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      Text(
        '',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
      ),
    ],
)
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just add widget inside bottomNavigationBar like this:

```
 return Scaffold(
    bottomNavigationBar: YOUR_WIDGET()
{...}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('AppBar'),
        ),
        body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: constraints.maxWidth, minHeight: constraints.maxHeight),
                  child: IntrinsicHeight(
                    child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: [
                          Text('header'),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.green,
                              child: Text('body'),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text('footer'),
                        ]
                    ),
                  )
              )
          );
        })
    );
  }
}
```